# Lemma about maximum, induction on natural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a family of types T which numerated with natural numbers. If some type is inhabited then the next type is also inhabited. (Can I say that family is "upward inhabited"?)

Let's assume that n-th type is inhabited.
How to prove that the type with number max(m,n) is also inhabited?

```
Parameter fam : nat->Type.
Axiom fam_mon : forall n, fam n -> fam (S n).
Lemma mxinh m : forall n, fam n -> fam (max m n).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, I am not sure where you are finding the difficulty, there is no special trouble in proving this given that `fam n` holds for arbitrarily large numbers after the witness.

A detailed proof is for example:

```
Parameter fam : nat->Type.
Axiom fam_mon : forall n, fam n -> fam n.+1.

Lemma fam_gt n k (hb : fam n) : fam (k + n).
Proof. by elim: k => //= k ihk; apply: fam_mon. Qed.

Lemma mxinh m n (hb : fam n) : fam (maxn n m).
Proof. by rewrite maxnE addnC; apply: fam_gt. Qed.

(* Another proof, YMMV *)  
Lemma fam_leq n m (hl : n <= m) (hb : fam n) : fam m.
Proof. by move/subnK: hl <-; apply: fam_gt. Qed.

Lemma mxinh' m n (hb : fam n) : fam (maxn n m).
Proof. exact: fam_leq (leq_maxl _ _) hb. Qed.
```

But indeed how to structure the theory is unclear unless we know a bit more about the use cases.

*edit* for those that prefer to use the "standard library":

```
Require Import PeanoNat.

Parameter fam : nat -> Type.
Axiom fam_mon : forall n, fam n -> fam (S n).

Lemma fam_gt n k (hb : fam n) : fam (n + k).
Proof. now rewrite Nat.add_comm; induction k; auto; apply fam_mon. Qed.

Lemma fam_leq n m (hl : n <= m) (hb : fam n) : fam m.
Proof. now rewrite <- (Nat.sub_add _ _ hl), Nat.add_comm; apply fam_gt. Qed.

Lemma mxinh m n (hb : fam n) : fam (max n m).
Proof. exact (fam_leq (Nat.le_max_l _ _) hb). Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use the standard library.

Comment: That changes nothing, proofs are the same; at most you may need to prove some missing lemma.

Comment: Ok, if I succeed in translation, I'll publish the solution here. Thanks again. The question is still open, though.

Comment: In this case the library used is no so important [as you can see in my edit] Don't tie yourself to one, the important thing here is what the proof is.